# cocoa touch - threading and animations

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am approaching the new ways of threading that cocoa offers.
Particularly, I am creating a new thread using the

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(myMethod) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

method.

Everything forks fine until now, but I am encountering a strange behavior and maybe you can clarify the things to me.
For instance, my thread is:

```
-(void)myMethod{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];  
    UIImage *img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"animage.png"];
    UIImageView *imgV=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
    [self.view addSubview:imgV];
    [imgV setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200)];
    [imgV setImage:img];
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:10.5];
    [imgV release];
    [pool release];
}
```

I cannot understand why my image is displayed after the sleepForTimeInterval command.
Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything relating to the UI should be done on the main thread. I think the correct sequence might be: (Note the "performSelectorOnMainThread" for the addView)

```
-(void)myMethod{
     NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];  
     UIImage *img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"animage.png"];
     UIImageView *imgV=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
     [imgV setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200)];
     [imgV setImage:img];
     [self.view performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addSubview:) withObject:imgV waitUntilDone:YES];
     [imgV release];
     [pool release];
}
```

Hope I remembered that right.

Comment: I tried this, got the same problem: if I add some other commands that include waiting in the thread, the image is displayed only once the method resolves. So how can I animate before the end of the thread?

Answer (score 0):

One problem in your code is that UI methods may only be called from the main thread. That's not causing your problem here, but you should fix it anyway.

The reason your image continues to be displayed is that you never remove the UIImageView from its superview (i.e. by sending it the `removeFromSuperview`).

---

**Edit, in response to clarification:**

If you were to be running that method on the main thread, your UI would be unresponsive for the 10.5 seconds that `sleepForTimeInterval:` is running, as UI updates only occur while the "main loop" is running and `sleepForTimeInterval:` prevents that. It's possible the same phenomenon is preventing the updates from your background thread from being processed, or it could just be a side effect of doing UI calls on a background thread. If you want to adjust UI from a background thread, you have to use `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` to have the method run on the main thread.

But for what you are trying to do here, you don't even need threads. Just add the image view in your main thread and use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` to remove the image view after 10.5 seconds.

```
UIImage *img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"animage.png"];
UIImageView *imgV = [[[UIImageView alloc] init] autorelease];
[self.view addSubview:imgV];
[imgV setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200)];
[imgV setImage:img];
[imgV performSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:nil afterDelay:10.5];
```

Comment: I am generating this thread in the main UI. Also, my problem is that my image is displayed, but just when the method ends. This prevents me from animating it in the same method.

Comment: Exactly, you're creating a new thread instead of making these UI calls on the main thread.

Comment: But I need the UIImageView to be generated occasionally (eg pressing of a button) and sequentially animated, so i thought of a thread. Now, with the `[self.view performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addSubview:) withObject:imgV waitUntilDone:NO];` instruction, it works fine.

Comment: I am really grateful as you clarified some things for me, but I think you haven't understood why I'm using a thread: I want to generate an UIImageView with the pressing of a button (instantiating it within the thread) then make it move and dealloc it when i'm done, everything within the thread. The main UI can perform other actions in the meantime.